# Why I get address when deferencing begin()?

Tags: list, pointers, iterator, dereference

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string*> *listStr = new std::list<std::string*>();

    listStr->push_back(new std::string("HI"));

    std::cout << *(listStr->begin()) << std::endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

I think I should be getting HI, but **I got address as output**

> 008A2B10  Press any key to continue . . .

I can't find my mistake..or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the pointer in the container.

You need one dereference for the iterator, and *another* one for the pointer to the string object.

Comment: haha thanks!! This is the first time i see a pattern like this

Answer (score 1):

It prints `string *`, not `string`.

To print `string`:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> *listStr = new std::list<std::string>();

    listStr->push_back(std::string("HI"));

    std::cout << *(listStr->begin()) << std::endl;  

    return 0;
}
```